# Face recognition algorithms

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I am trying to work with MSRA-CFW dataset for face recognition. I have tried two algorithms for this dataset:

Eigenfaces and
FisherFaces

Eigenfaces, as expected, performed poorly (because of its sensitivity to variations in light and head orientation). However even FisherFaces did not give satisfactory results.

Which algorithm should I use for this dataset? Or maybe even for any other dataset. Would convolutional neural networks work in this setting ? Also LBP features are provided with this dataset. Would these be better than convolutional neural networks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent face recognition library that I tested and which is based on a paper from Google. It has the best recognition rate from an open source ~92%)
https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/

Internally it uses convolutional neural networks model trained on 500K face.
The only problem is that it doesn't recognize an unknown person, and it sees it as the nearest face from the database.